# HTML form invalid popup when it shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a question about ignoring an HTML invalid field message that is stopping my form from submitting. In my case I am using a plugin for allowing users to crop uploaded profile pictures. I've linked the plugin below.

http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/

It uses this piece of code here: `zoomer.step = '0.01';`. And in some JS I have written I am using the `.valid()` JQuery function. For some reason this fails and says:

`Please enter a multiple of 0.01.`

Is there any way to ignore this error or fix the plugin? Theoretically this plugin shouldn't even be throwing this error because the slider should be automatically incrementing by 0.01. Hence the `step = '0.01'` piece of code.

Can anybody help me out? Thanks.

**NOTE**: **Removing the step attribute causes zooming in the plugin to not work!**

**Edit**:

Code in question:

[image]

Here's my JS that checks if the form is valid.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        var attr = $(this).attr('submitted');
        if (typeof attr === typeof undefined || attr === false) {
            if ($(this).valid()) {                      // Issue causing line
                $(this).attr('submitted', 'submitted');
                $(this).submit();
            } else {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Picture of the plugin with the slider:

[image]

Comment: this happens only when you don't change the input (range) or it also happens after you change the input?

Comment: Could you show me a page saying .valid() is a jquery function/method? http://api.jquery.com/